# In javascript: "document" is not defined error

Tags: javascript, java

I want to use Karspersky widget in my java project but I did not run html code in java. I am trying to run only js but I get an error:

> Caused by: `<eval>:31` **ReferenceError**: "document" is not defined

What can I do?

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("/home/havelsan/Desktop/widget.js");
            engine.eval(reader);
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

widget.js

```
// Cybermap v2 widget loader
(function() {

function setup_widget(div) {
    var config = {
        width: div.dataset.width || 640,
        height: div.dataset.height || 640,
        language: div.dataset.language || 'en',
        theme: div.dataset.theme || 'dark',
        type: div.dataset.type || 'dynamic'
    };
    console.log("config.language >> " + config.language);
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

    var baseURI = 'https://cybermap.kaspersky.com/';
    iframe.src = baseURI + (config.type == 'dynamic' ? 'widget.html' : 'widget-static.html');

    iframe.style.width = config.width + 'px';
    iframe.style.height = config.height + 'px';
    iframe.style.border = 'none';

    iframe.onload = function() {
        console.log("config.language >> " + config.language);
        var msg = JSON.stringify({ config: config });
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(msg, '*');
    };
    console.log("config.language >> " + config.language);
    div.appendChild(iframe);
}

var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.kas-cybermap-widget');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
    setup_widget(divs[i]);
}

}());
```

Comment: That JavaScript code is written to run as part of a web page. You can't just run it outside the context of a web page, because then there's no `document` and everything that's connected to it (such as an iframe, div's etc.).

Comment: Do not have a way to operate in this way? or Can i run html page in java?

Comment: What functionality do you require from this widget.js?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem another way. I used [JxBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser). It can be used with JFrame in Jpanel.